# Trigonometry for Lengths of Similar Triangles

Tags: trigonometry

I am given a solution where we know that E is the midpoint of AD, but I cannot see why we know this?
[Picture of Question at hand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4JsD.png)

Comment: I can't see the picture.

Comment: Ok, I had some problems uploading it but when I click the link it shows it to me. I'll try to see if I can find the problem. Thanks

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures cannot be searched and are inaccessible to those using screen readers.

Comment: OK thanks, I am new to the community and still learning the formats. For reference, with questions that are quite difficult to describe, what is the preferred method to allow understanding in your opinion?

Comment: I used an HTTP*S* plugin.  Removing the `s`, I can finally see the picture.  After viewing the picture, I realise that the comment from http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189 doesn't apply to this case.

Comment: Thanks to all replies for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Your picture]

$\triangle ABE\ $ is an equilateral triangle, so $\ AE=BE\ $, $\ \angle ABE=60^{\rm o}$

Also, $\ \angle EBD=90^{\rm o}-\angle ABE=90^{\rm o}-60^{\rm o}=30^{\rm o}=\angle BDE$

Thus $\ \triangle BDE\ $ is an isosceles triangle, which means that
$$DE=BE=AE$$

Hence $E$ is the midpoint of $AD$

Answer (score 0):

since the angle at $E$ is also $60^{\circ}$ and from $30^{\circ}+120^{\circ}+x=180^{\circ}$ we get $x=30^{\circ}$

Answer (score 0):

Since $ABE$ has two $60^\circ$ angles, it must be equilateral.

Lets define $M$ as the midpoint of  $AB.$  And lets connect M to E.

This divides your figure into 4 similar triangles.

Since $AM = MB$ then not only are $AME$ and $BME$ similar, they are congruent.

It is easy enough to show that all 4 triangles are congruent.  And with that, $AE = ED$

Answer (score 0):

From the diagram, we can observe that $\triangle ABE$ is an equilateral triangle i.e. all sides of the triangle is equal. Hence, $AE$=$BA$=$EB$.

Further, we can also observe that $\triangle BED$ is an isosceles triangle, that is, two sides of the triangle are equal i.e. $EB$=$ED$

Therefore, since $AE$=$BE$=$ED$, we can easily conclude that $E$ is the midpoint of $AD$.

Answer (score 0):

Because BED is a right isosceles triangle, EC is going to be a midline. This is because EC is squared with BD (I don't know what that line is called in English). With ECD is similar to ABD => CD/BD = ED/AD = 1/2 => E is the midpoint of AD